# How to use Bi-sectioning?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that uses bisection to find a fixed monthly rate that will pay off a balance with a month. This is what I have at the moment and what I get is an infinite loop but I'm not sure why.

```
balance = 3329
tempB = balance
annualInterestRate = 0.2
monthlyIntrestRate = (annualInterestRate/12)
low = balance / 12
high = (balance * (1 + monthlyIntrestRate)**12)/12
avg = (high + low)/2
epsilon = 0.01



while abs(balance - epsilon) >= 0.01:
    avg = (high + low)/2
    for i in range(12):
        monthlyUnpaidBalance = balance - avg
        updatedBalanceMonth = monthlyUnpaidBalance + (monthlyIntrestRate * monthlyUnpaidBalance)
        balance = updatedBalanceMonth
    if abs(balance - epsilon) <= 0.01:
        print(avg)
        break
    else:
        balance = tempB
        if abs(updatedBalanceMonth) > epsilon:
            low = avg
        elif abs(updatedBalanceMonth) < epsilon:
            high = avg
```

I have a much simpler code that does the same thing but it is inefficient the code to it is

```
MinPay = 10
balance = 3329
tempB = balance
annualInterestRate = 0.2
monthlyIntrestRate = (annualInterestRate/12)



while balance >= 0:
    for i in range(12):
        monthlyUnpaidBalance = balance - MinPay
        updatedBalanceMonth = monthlyUnpaidBalance + (monthlyIntrestRate * monthlyUnpaidBalance)
        balance = updatedBalanceMonth
    if balance <= 0:
        print(MinPay)
        break
    else:
        MinPay += 10
        balance = tempB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if you have infinite loop, I would suggest you run your code under `pdb` and do step trace to find why the loop doesn't end.

In your case, I think the issue is on these lines:

```
if abs(updatedBalanceMonth) > epsilon:
    low = avg
elif abs(updatedBalanceMonth) < epsilon:
    high = avg
```

which `abs()` should generally be greater than epsilon. I see your intention is that if your monthly pay is too much so the resulting balance is negative then you should set `high` to `avg` so you try with a lower pay on next search iteration. So you should remove `abs()` in these conditions.

But I would suggest you make your code easier to read as follows, especially that's intended for finance application:

```
balance = 3329
rate = 0.2  # 20% p.a.
lopay = 1
hipay = balance
epsilon = 0.01

monthly = 100  # search start
pv = sum([monthly/((1+rate/12)**i) for i in range(1,13)])

while abs(balance - pv) >= epsilon:
    if pv > balance:
        hipay = monthly
    else:
        lopay = monthly
    monthly = (hipay + lopay) / 2
    pv = sum([monthly/((1+rate/12)**i) for i in range(1,13)])
```

which you simply compute the present value of the 12 monthly payments and compare that to the starting balance.

Comment: They gave me a test case where the balance is (320000) and the final answer is 29157.09. Using my code (changing the abs problem) I got the answer 29591.88, with the code that you provided I received 29643.04. Could it be that my epsilon is too big?

Comment: Check with Excel, `=PMT(0.2/12, 12, 320000)` gives 29643.04. So your test case is wrong (what is the interest rate?)

Comment: its 0.2 annual interest so 1/60 monthly interest.

Comment: That doesn't tie out with Excel. Better confirm your test case is valid.

Comment: Turns out I forgot to remove one of the absolute values which was the reason I got the wrong answers. Both ways worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It gets stuck an infinite loop because your expression:

```py
abs(balance - episolon)
```

when it is evaluated in the `while` loop exit condition never actually changes.

If you get stuck in a `while` loop, you can try little modifications to code like this:

```py
balance = 3329
tempB = balance
annualInterestRate = 0.2
monthlyIntrestRate = (annualInterestRate/12)
low = balance / 12
high = (balance * (1 + monthlyIntrestRate)**12)/12
avg = (high + low)/2
epsilon = 0.01

count = 1

while abs(balance - epsilon) >= 0.01 and count <= 100:
    print(abs(balance - epsilon))
    avg = (high + low)/2
    for i in range(12):
        monthlyUnpaidBalance = balance - avg
        updatedBalanceMonth = monthlyUnpaidBalance + (monthlyIntrestRate * monthlyUnpaidBalance)
        balance = updatedBalanceMonth
    if abs(balance - epsilon) <= 0.01:
        print(avg)
        break
    else:
        balance = tempB
        if abs(updatedBalanceMonth) > epsilon:
            low = avg
        elif abs(updatedBalanceMonth) < epsilon:
            high = avg
    count += 1
```

In this case, the iterations are capped and you can see the value that you are evaluating in your exit condition as:

```
3328.99
3328.99
3328.99
3328.99
3328.99
3328.99
3328.99
3328.99
3328.99
3328.99
(continuing)
```

Your going to need to refine your logic so that you can actually hit an exit condition.